# Aren't vacuous statements True and False simultaneously?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, logic, quantifiers

Wikipedia states "a vacuous truth is a statement that asserts that all members of the empty set have a certain property". Clearly the statement: 'all elements of said (empty) set possess said property' is vacuously true. However, one could argue that the negation of the statement: 'no elements in said set posses said property' is also true. Shouldn't that mean that the statement is both true and false. I understand there may be slightly different definitions of what constitutes a vacuous statement, but I suppose this particular issue will show up nevertheless.

Comment: "Vacuous truth" means a statement that is true but mathematically inconsequential.  It comes up with more than empty sets.  "If 9 is even, then it is prime".  That's true, but (arguably) never useful.  That's why it is called vacuous.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You did not negate the statement "all elements of a set S have property X" correctly.  The opposite of "all elements of a set S have property X" is *not* "no elements of set S have property X".

The opposite of "all elements of a set S have property X" is "some element of S does not have property X".  If S is empty, "some element of S does not have property X" is definitely *not* true.

Comment: Your negation is also missing a "not" as it should be the existence of an element *without* the property.

Comment: Yes, of course.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft Corrected.